# About anti-commutation of gauge charged Fermionic quantum fields

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory, grassmannians

[Please correct anything I might say wrong in what follows!]

For everything that follows I am thinking in the context of a supersymmetric QFT. Hence I guess everytime I say "spacetime" it needs to be understood to be a super-manifold. I guess this does not affect the fact that all Hilbert spaces that are used in the following are still "ordinary" Hilbert spaces.

Say $\chi$ is a Fermionic quantum field charged under some gauge group i.e it is having an interaction term with the gauge field in the Lagrangian of the QFT. So I guess at some heuristic level one can think of a quantum field $\chi$ as being a map from the spacetime to a tensor product space of the form, $GL(V)\otimes L({\cal{H}})$ where $V$ is some finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ supporting an irreducible representation of a compact Lie group (the gauge group) and $L({\cal{H}})$ is the space of linear maps ${\cal {H}} \rightarrow {\cal {H}}$ for some Hilbert space ${\cal H}$ over $\mathbb{C}$.

Now quantum states made out of $\chi$ need to be gauge invariant and that forces us to look at states to be of the form, $\textrm{Tr}[\chi^n]$ for $n$ an integer where something like $\textrm{Tr}[\chi^2]$ is supposed to indicate $\chi_{ab}\chi_{ba}$ where $a, b$ are the gauge indices (corresponding to a choice of basis of $V$) and something like $\chi_{ab}$ is a map from the spacetime to $L(\cal{H})$.

Now in the above notation to prove that such a $\textrm{Tr}[\chi^2]$ is actually 0 we need to write an equation like "$\chi_{ab}\chi_{ba} = - \chi_{ba}\chi_{ab}$". Such an anti-commutation statement would be easy to understand if these $\chi_{ab}$ were just Grassman variables but they are not so here. Here each $\chi_{ab}$ is itself an operator on the Hilbert space!

- Now what exactly does the anti-commutation hypothesis on $\chi$ need to be for such a statement like $\textrm{Tr}[\chi^2] =0$ to make sense? (..if we just think of $\chi_{ab}$ to be like infinite-dimensional matrices whose entries are Grassman numbers then such an anti-commutation seems not possible to derive..)

---

One option seems to be to say that we will always imagine each $\chi_{ab}$ to have an oscillator expansion like, $\chi_{ab} \sim \sum_{\vec{p}} a_{\vec{p},ab}$ and then we postulate that these Hilbert space operators $a_{\vec{q},c,d}$ anti-commute amongst themselves irrespective of their momentum or the gauge index.

- Is this the right way to think about it? If yes then what is the right way to define a "space of mutually anti-commuting linear operators on a Hilbert space"? (..note that the same Hilbert space will also have to be acted on by ``real" linear operators coming from the Bosonic fields co-existing in the same theory and possibly charged under the same gauge group..)